# React Datepicker react-datepicker__day Activate only the dates in the month

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2pmX.png)

I just want to activate the date of the month. Is there a way? If I disable the rest, the navigation function disappears.

```
if (isLoad) {
    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            placeholderText='YYYY.MM.DD'
            onChange={(date) => handleLocalDateChange(date)} // Call the new function here
            formatWeekDay={(nameOfWeek) => nameOfWeek.toString().slice(0, 3)}
            useWeekdaysShort={true}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use minDate and maxDate

```
<DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        placeholderText='YYYY.MM.DD'
        minDate={new Date('01-01-2023')}
        maxDate={new Date('01-02-2023')}
        onChange={(date) => handleLocalDateChange(date)} // Call the new function here
        formatWeekDay={(nameOfWeek) => nameOfWeek.toString().slice(0, 3)}
        useWeekdaysShort={true}
    />
```